# How should i deal with sector errors if i want to clone HDD to SSD?

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, clone, bad-sectors

I recently purchased a Samsung 870 EVO SSD that is going to replace my Seagate Barracuda 1TB HDD as my main drive.
My intention was to simply clone the drive using Macrium Reflect but i got [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cREHF.png) error after a couple of minutes.

I then remembered how my drive has been giving me [sector errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QKZRn.png) as well as [other errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RXJ8d.png) and i'm 99% sure that's causing the Data error in Macrium Reflect.

I don't know if using [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m36Rc.png) option for the cloning will make a difference but i'm pretty scared to do anything at this point.

Comment: Make a image of the drive by first ticking the Ignore bad sectors setting in Defaults>advanced backup settings, once the image completes, the apply the image to the new drive.

Answer (score 0):

Making a copy while this is on-going is something you want to do if you are rescuing data. If it is your intention to use the new drive as replacement, then this is not a good idea because you will be cloning the bad sectors too.

In that case, it is better to only copy the files using a normal file copy, and if you also have an OS install on that drive, perform a clean install on the drive first before copying files over.